# What is the difference between approximations of $\int_1^4 \frac {12}{x} \mathrm{d}x$ between right and left hand Riemann sums?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

This is how far I have gone:

Right-hand: $X_k^. = a + \Delta X *k$, $\Delta X=\frac{4-1}{n}=\frac 3n$, $X_k^. = 1+\frac 3n * k$,

$\sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k^.)*\Delta X$,

$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac {12}{1+\frac 3n *k} * \frac 3n$, $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac {36}{n+3k}$

Left-hand: $X_k^. = a + \Delta X *(k-1)$, $\Delta X=\frac{4-1}{n}=\frac 3n$, $X_k^. = 1+\frac 3n * (k-1)$,

$\sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k^.)*\Delta X$

$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac {12}{1+\frac 3n *(k-1)} * \frac 3n$, $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac {36}{n+3(k-1)}$

From here I have no idea how to bring them to series formulas and calculate the difference?

Comment: Try doing an example with a low number of divisions so that you can do the computation without dealing with summation notation.  You will see that you get cancelation of all but one term in the right hand sum and one term in the left hand sum.

Comment: I did not get what you said. I apologize.

Comment: That works for any function, which is how this should be done.

Comment: @AmanKhan If we take $\Delta X=1$, the left hand sum will be $f(1)+f(2)+f(3)$ and the right hand sum will be $f(2)+f(3)+f(4)$

Comment: So we do not need to initially solve both right and left-hand sums first and then do substruction? Why we take $\Delta X=1$ if $\Delta X= \frac 3n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $l=k-1$,

\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{36}{n+3k}- \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{36}{n+3(k-1)}&=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{36}{n+3k}- \sum_{l=0}^{n-1} \frac{36}{n+3l} \\
&=\left(\frac{36}{n+3n}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{36}{n+3k}\right) - \left( \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} \frac{36}{n+3l} +\frac{36}{n}\right)\\
&=\frac{36}{n+3n}+\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{36}{n+3k} -  \sum_{l=1}^{n-1} \frac{36}{n+3l}\right) -\frac{36}{n}\\
&=\frac{36}{4n}-\frac{36}{n}\\
&= -\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{36}{n}\\
&= - \frac{27}{n}\end{align}

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the answer is given as an integer? I am lost.

Comment: hmm perhaps more context is needed? are you told what is $n$?

Comment: There is no n, but graph image on the bottom has 3 blocks, between 1 and 4. Does it mean that n=3?

Comment: $n$ is the number of blocks.

Comment: Cool. Can you please explain me why you have n-1 on top of the second sum which has l=0? And why l=0?

Comment: I did a change of variable, when $k=1$, we have $l=0$. when $k=n$, $l=n-1$.